# Same Url but different content, why?

Tags: javascript, html

On this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink, about the bottom, before "specifications" section, there is a "Open in Jsfiddle" button, when you click it, you will be lead to a jsfiddle page demonstrating some codes. The problem is, this page's URL is just `https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/`. I am not totally ignorant of JF, usually to display certain code, there is a random combination of letters and numbers following the top level domain. But this one got me perplexed, if you click or input the URL directly, you will be lead to a page with no codes at all. I know there is some javascript involved, but how is this achieved exactly?

====***** Dummy codes(Since there is a link to jsfiddle, it keeps asking me for code) *****=====

```
div{display:flex}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a link, when you click on "Open in jsfiddle" you just send POST form to jsfiddle site.